# UITableView with paging, each cell is a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to use a `UITableView` to create a vertically paging view and benefit from the cell reuse that the `UITableView` offers.

Each cell in the `UITableView` contains a `UIScrollView` with zooming enabled (as a child of the cell's `contentView`) that I will call a `ZoomingScrollView`.

What works:

- Zooming the `ZoomingScrollView` works all the time.
- The table view
  scrolls and pages fine most of the time.

**What doesn't work:**

- Paging the table view
  doesn't work when the `ZoomingScrollView` starts zooming vertically
  (eg. it starts responding to vertical dragging events).

Usually, if you embed a series of `ZoomingScrollView` inside a `UIScrollView`, there is no problem to have paging working even when the `ZoomingScrollView` are zoomed in.

I understand that in my case, I have a several intermediate views between the `UIScrollView` and the `ZoomingScrollView` (`UITableViewCell`, its content view...). I imagine that this prevents the two scroll views to interact properly.

My question: Is there any way to work around this problem, or should I just go back to using just a `UIScrollView` and `ZoomingScrollViews` without relying on a `UITableView` for recycling.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, saw it on iOS Dev Weekly today: https://github.com/acoomans/ACReuseQueue?utm_campaign=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_131&utm_medium=email&utm_source=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly

Comment: Thanks. This would help if I went back to the other implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this in an app. I had 5 data intensive UIViewControllers in one scroll view with paging. I didn't bother to reuse the views or anything like that - and they perform very well.

How many views do you have? You could consider taking a second look at your design and wonder why you're doing this... can things be factored out?

My gut is to ditch the table view.

Comment: I may have a very large number of very big views. Reuse is necessary.